# Can I create a noise texture with a "darker end"?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I made a logo in photoshop a while ago and I am now trying to make it in Blender.

I'm really new to nodes and I somehow managed to create something that looks quite like the real deal. The only thing left to do with the texture is to make it have a "gradient limit" or something that'll make it turn darker after a while.

I'm not a certified explainer so I attached two images.

NOTE: the "PTV" is from the reference image so I haven't gotten that fixed

What I'm getting
[image: What I'm getting]

What I'm trying to get

[image: What I'm trying to get]

Comment: Couldn't you just tweak the darker stop of your color ramp node further to the left ? If you want non-linear distribution you can try plugging a map range node with a smooth interpolation or use a RGB Curves for more granular settings. Let me know if you can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple materials to an object in Blender. In *Edit Mode* just select the faces of the outer part and assign them to a new material. In the example I've done this for the outer, middle (white line), and the inner part.

The "darker end" can be created with a [*ColorRamp*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/color_ramp.html#color-ramp-node) and a [*MixRGB*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html#mix-node) node in the node setup. Set the mode of the *MixRGB* node to *Multiply* and factor to 1.0. To move the "darker end" of the outer part to the bottom right I had to add a *Mapping* node and rotate the position a bit.

[image: Node setup for the outer material]

The shading for the inner area looks similar. Just swapped the grey values of the  *ColorRamp* to darken the top right part of this area a bit.
[image: Nodes setup for the inner part of the logo]

If the colors appear too dark you might need more light in your scene. The logo on the screenshot is 3m tall (to get the shading right) and there is a 3000W point light, 3m radius (affects the shadow softness).

With a [*Solidify modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) you can add some depth/3D to your logo and it gets some nice light reflections. Add a plane as background to see the drop shadow if you want.

I removed the Alpha channel since it's always 1 and it had no use(?). If you activate the [*Node Wranger*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html#node-wrangler) addon that ships with Blender you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to get a preview of the selected node. This can help a lot to see what's going on.